# for ... of statement: goto next element of iterable

Tags: javascript

Given I have a `for...of` statement like this

```js
for (const element of array1) {
  if(element.name === 'stackoverflow') {
    // goto next element
  }

  // more statements
}
```

How can I go to next element in `array1` without processing further statements inside the current iteration?

I want to avoid complex `if/else` constructs.

`return` and `break` don't seem to work as per [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

> In for...of loops, abrupt iteration termination can be caused by
>   break, throw or return. In these cases, the iterator is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `continue`:

```
for (const element of array1) {
  if(element.name === 'stackoverflow') {
    continue;
  }

  // more statements
}
```